# PL/SQL Error - exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, plsql

I'm currently trying to write a PL/SQL script that will gather information from my saleinv table that matches the serial number inputted by the user. Currently, my code is returning the error Error message is ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows. If someone could explain to me how to fix the issue, it would be very appreciated. My code is below.

```
    ACCEPT p_saleinv PROMPT 'Enter sales invoice number: '
    VARIABLE g_output VARCHAR2(4000)

    DECLARE

 v_ABC NUMBER(4);
 v_DEF EXCEPTION;
 v_freightcost car.freightcost%TYPE;
 v_totalcost car.totalcost%TYPE;

CURSOR saleinvoicelist IS
SELECT *
FROM saleinv
WHERE saleinv = '&p_saleinv';

BEGIN

SELECT COUNT(*)
INTO v_ABC  
FROM saleinv
WHERE saleinv = '&p_saleinv';

SELECT freightcost,totalcost
INTO  v_freightcost,v_totalcost
FROM car c, saleinv si
WHERE  c.serial = si.serial
AND   c.cname  = si.cname;


IF v_ABC = '0' THEN

  RAISE v_DEF;

ELSE 

   FOR v_saleinv IN saleinvoicelist LOOP
      :g_output := :g_output||TRIM(v_saleinv.saleinv)||' ';
      :g_output := :g_output||TRIM(v_saleinv.cname)||' ';
      :g_output := :g_output||TRIM(v_saleinv.saledate)||' ';
      :g_output := :g_output||TRIM(v_saleinv.serial)||' ';
      :g_output := :g_output||TO_CHAR(v_freightcost,'122345.69')||CHR(10);
      :g_output := :g_output||TO_CHAR(v_saleinv.tax,'12345.99')||' ';
      :g_output := :g_output||TO_CHAR(v_saleinv.licfee,'123.76')||' ';
      :g_output := :g_output||TO_CHAR(v_saleinv.commission,'1234.59')||' ';
      :g_output := :g_output||TO_CHAR(v_totalcost,'123489.97')||CHR(10);
      :g_output := :g_output||TO_CHAR(v_saleinv.totalprice,'12345.45')||' ';

   END LOOP;

END IF;

EXCEPTION

 WHEN v_DEF THEN

  ROLLBACK WORK;

  :g_output := 'Such data does not exist.';

  WHEN OTHERS THEN

   ROLLBACK WORK;

   -- check error message
   :g_output := 'Error'||CHR(10);
   :g_output := :g_output||'Error code is '||SQLCODE||CHR(10);
   :g_output := :g_output||'Error message is '||SQLERRM;

  END;
   /
   PRINT g_output
```

Comment: You need a `GROUP BY` someField as well where you have `Count(*)`

Comment: @Ofisora - only if the query's projection includes some non-aggregated columns. That's not the case here, so no need for a GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely cause of this error would be the below select

```
SELECT freightcost,totalcost
INTO  v_freightcost,v_totalcost
FROM car c, saleinv si
WHERE  c.serial = si.serial
AND   c.cname  = si.cname;
```

because you are selecting into variables the select can only return one row. I would assume that the serial number that you are using will return multiple rows from this select.  You need to ensure that it returns a unique row.

Answer (score 0):

Below SELECT INTO statement expects only a singluar output in the singular variable. You need to either handle exceptions or modifiy the code, if you expect more output then use FOR LOOP.
Hope below snippet helps.

```
ACCEPT p_saleinv PROMPT 'Enter sales invoice number: '
VARIABLE g_output VARCHAR2(4000)
DECLARE
  v_ABC NUMBER(4);
  v_DEF EXCEPTION;
  v_freightcost car.freightcost%TYPE;
  v_totalcost car.totalcost%TYPE;
  CURSOR saleinvoicelist
  IS
    SELECT * FROM saleinv WHERE saleinv = '&p_saleinv';
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_ABC FROM saleinv WHERE saleinv = '&p_saleinv';


  BEGIN
  SELECT freightcost,
    totalcost
  INTO v_freightcost,
    v_totalcost
  FROM car c,
    saleinv si
  WHERE c.serial = si.serial
  AND c.cname    = si.cname;
  EXCEPTION 
     WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
  dbms_output.put_line('Too many rows fetched');
     RETURN;
     WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  dbms_output.put_line('No rows fetched');
    RETURN;
  IF v_ABC       = '0' THEN
    RAISE v_DEF;
  ELSE
    FOR v_saleinv IN saleinvoicelist
    LOOP
      :g_output := :g_output||TRIM(v_saleinv.saleinv)||' ';
      :g_output := :g_output||TRIM(v_saleinv.cname)||' ';
      :g_output := :g_output||TRIM(v_saleinv.saledate)||' ';
      :g_output := :g_output||TRIM(v_saleinv.serial)||' ';
      :g_output := :g_output||TO_CHAR(v_freightcost,'122345.69')||CHR(10);
      :g_output := :g_output||TO_CHAR(v_saleinv.tax,'12345.99')||' ';
      :g_output := :g_output||TO_CHAR(v_saleinv.licfee,'123.76')||' ';
      :g_output := :g_output||TO_CHAR(v_saleinv.commission,'1234.59')||' ';
      :g_output := :g_output||TO_CHAR(v_totalcost,'123489.97')||CHR(10);
      :g_output := :g_output||TO_CHAR(v_saleinv.totalprice,'12345.45')||' ';
    END LOOP;
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
WHEN v_DEF THEN
  ROLLBACK WORK;
  :g_output := 'Such data does not exist.';
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  ROLLBACK WORK;
  -- check error message
  :g_output := 'Error'||CHR(10);
  :g_output := :g_output||'Error code is '||SQLCODE||CHR(10);
  :g_output := :g_output||'Error message is '||SQLERRM;
END;
/
```